Number of concurrent connections vs number of threads in spring boot 3
I am asking the community here as i am confused with contradicting info i am finding about this on web. I have read that "By default, Tomcat in Spring Boot has a thread pool consisting of a maximum of 200 threads" . At the same time i have also read that "By default, the number of requests that Spring Boot can handle simultaneously = maximum connections (8192) + maximum waiting number (100), resulting in 8292" . So is it like using 200 threads spring boot can handle 8192 connections simultaneously at a time ? or one of the information above is wrong . We are using Spring boot 3.x.x in our apps.
In our app logs I can see that, for example "09:58:52.763 [http-nio-8085-exec-488]" which makes me to believe its using 488th thread , but if there are only 200 threads how can it go to 488. So confused :(.  I humbly request knowledgeable folks to give more clarity or give me a document reference i can read abt.

Spring/Tomcat uses Non-Blocking IO (NIO) threads. This means that a single thread can manage multiple connections and maintain them for a duration determined by the keepAlive parameter

Thank you @John Williams . So when i see 09:58:52.763 [http-nio-8085-exec-488] it means its using 488th connection which is managed by one of the 200th thread available right ? Which means i should not worry abt application performance when i see that value more than 200 as it can go until 8292. is that correct understanding?

No, think http-nio-8085-exec-488 is the thread, not the connection. My guess is that the thread ids don't start at 1 and/or they are not sequential.

Yes, you don't need to worry about going beyond the configured max number of threads.

This is my basic understanding of Tomcat threads and concurrency:

The concurrency limit 8192 says how many simultaneous connections Tomcat can handle. It does not mean that Tomcat handles all of them at once.

These 200 threads manage the concurrent connections. The threads themselves are reused. Moreover, not all the connections are active, a good number of them can be waiting.


Honestly, I have no idea about what exactly http-nio-8085-exec-488 represents. Perhaps some of the threads are removed and new ones are created but it is my wild guess. Perhaps the number is not related to the threads at all. I'd rather wait for someone more enlightened for a correct explanation.

"a good number of them can be waiting" - as in swapped out of thread context. There will also be connections waiting if the incoming connections is greater than the max.

So imagine we have 200 threads, if thread number 1 is dead, app will create new thread which will show as http-nio-8085-exec-201 and it wont use the same number  as 1 ? . If so over the time this number will go way more right ?
